# how to operate AJAX by axios with react

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I'm new to use `axios` with `react` so, I want to ask some questions.

Let me explain what I want to make first.

Someone(**A**)  clicks `likes` button about Someone(**B**)'s post and (**B**) will get a notification because of `+1 likes` by `axios` after few seconds.

I wonder how these processes exactly is going?
I think clicking `likes` button by (**A**) makes the number of (**B**)'s `likes` in `DATABASE` changed, but How (**B**) get this updated number of `likes`?? I understand that if (**B**)'s page is refreshed, (**B**) will get the updated number of `likes`.

However, Without F5(refresh), how (**B**) get the updated number of `likes` by `axios`?? Does `axios` check every seconds whether the data from `DATABASE` is changed or not?

Or it is related with `redux`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this propose you can check the database in some interval times with axios. but a better way is to you something like [Socket.io](https://github.com/sturmenta/react-web-vector-icons/blob/master/test/webpack.config.js). or [Socket Cluster](https://socketcluster.io/) or [Web RTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC). with these technologies `B` can understand someone give it like.

Answer (score 1):

> Without F5(refresh), how (B) get the updated number of likes by axios??

No, axios is similar to AJAX. It cannot push a notification automatically.

In order to get real time notification, here are few things you can do.
1. Use pusher notification, socket.io etc (Highly recommended).
2. Keep page refreshing in some time interval (Not recommended at all).

Example
[Pusher notification](https://pusher.com/)

Also, its not related with redux. Redux helps you to update redux store.